# Explicit instantiation of a deleted function template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, explicit-instantiation, deleted-functions

If a function template is marked as deleted, is it allowed to explicitly instantiate it as in the example:

```
template<class T>
int foo(T) = delete;

template int foo(int);
```

Clang and GCC allows it, while MSVC prints the error:

```
error C2280: 'int foo<int>(int)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/49hfqnr4f

Which compiler is right here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang and GCC are right. MSVC is probably referring to the following rule ([[dcl.fct.def.delete]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#delete)):

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.

An explicit instantiation definition is a declaration, so it is allowed.

Although, to be fair, it's not clear what "refers" means in this context, so there is some room for language lawyering. But it's clear that, in general, the mere instantiation of a template to produce a deleted function definition is allowed. [[temp.inst]/3.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#3.2) also mentions the implicit instantiation of deleted member functions that occurs when class templates are implicitly instantiated. If instantiating a templated entity to produce a deleted function definition were ill-formed, it wouldn't be possible to use class templates like `std::atomic` that have a deleted copy constructor. Your program merely does explicitly what happens implicitly under those circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify that I properly understand *an explicit instantiation definition is a declaration*. If one removes the body of function template and requests its explicit instantiation, shall it be an error as in this example https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WMs5deGha?

Comment: @Fedor I'm not sure what that has to do with the answer. But see http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#7